# PID file with problematic folder info

Tags: debian, filesystems

I have a .PID file that has this appearance when I do `ls -al`:

```
-?????????  ? ?       ?          ?            ? x10monitor.pid
```

I'm not having much success getting rid of it. Have tried rebooting, CHMOD, etc.

Commands all return:

```
cannot access `x10monitor.pid': Input/output error
```

Suggestions on how to proceed?

EDIT:

```
stat /var/run/x10monitor.pid
stat: cannot stat `./x10monitor.pid': Input/output error

chmod u+x /var/run/x10monitor.pid
chmod: cannot access `x10monitor.pid': Input/output error
```

EDIT:

I was able to mount the drive on another system and `fsck` it. Lots of errors. After accepting them all the system was able to boot and is working ok.

Comment: Which file system do you use? Which version of Debian and kernel? What does `stat ./*` show? What is the complete output of `ls -al` (including `.` and `..` entries)? --- **Edit:** Did you check the file system integrity (`fsck`)?

Answer (score 1):

The filename begins with the "-" character, which the commands are probably interpreting as a switch. Try this:

```
rm -i ./-*
```

Prepending `./` (redundantly specifying that it is in the current directory) will distinguish it from a switch. The `-i` argument to `rm` will cause it to prompt you before deleting, so you can verify that you are actually deleting the file you intend to.

Comment: I do not see the `-` character at the beginning of the file name. It is at the beginning of the file type and permission string. Notice that the `ls` command has the `-l` option.

Comment: I see. My mistake. I thought that entire line was the file name. It looks like the permission issue discussed in this Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541533/only-questionmarks-in-linux-dirlisting ...Try `chmod u+x .`

Comment: `chmod u+x x10monitor.pid` gives the same error message. I'm going to try mounting the volume on another system and doing fsck.

Comment: I mean literally: `chmod u+x .`--the containing directory--not the file.

Comment: @Woody: But attention! The `.` directory entry itself could be inaccessible too. The solution could be: `stat /var/run` --- checking the access rights, `chmod u+x /var/run` --- enabling the executable right (the right to access the metadata of files). It also depends on who is the owner of the directory.

Comment: @pabouk: He did not specify a directory to `ls`, and he didn't mention `/var/run` in the original post. He could have checked the permissions and owner by running `stat .`, but `chmod` would have told him if he lacked permission. Regardless, knowing that it was `/var/run` we can guess that it was owned by root, and he was probably running as root. If we had known from the beginning that it was a system directory, `fsck` would have been the obvious answer--root would have been able to stat the file regardless of permissions.